# unable to start a aplication with tmux at startup

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi, tmux

I'm trying to start an application (newsbeuter) at boot but I can't.
I'm tyring with:

```
tmux new-session -d -s main
tmux new-window -t main:1 '/usr/bin/newsbeuter'
```

Tmux is up but the newsbeuter dont start:

```
ps -ef | grep -i tmux 

root      2118     1  0 16:09 ?        00:00:00 tmux new-session -d -s main 
pi        2245  2211  0 16:09 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i tmux pi@raspberrypi 

ps -ef | grep -i news 

pi        2247  2211  0 16:09 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i news
```

Could you help me please?
Many thanks and sorry for my english!

Comment: Do you need to quote `/usr/bin/newsbeuter`?

Comment: I thing yes by the examples that I see

Comment: What happens when you run `/usr/bin/newsbeuter` in terminal without tmux?

Comment: It executes the aplication normally

Comment: You don't need to use quotes, but I don't think it hurts, either.

Comment: Have you tried running these same commands from an interactive shell? How are you trying to run these at startup?

Comment: Hi. In interactive shell I dont have any problem. I execute this shell script from calling my script from /etc/rc.local

Answer (score 0):

Upon startup, Newsbeuter will look for URLs file, first in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/.config/newsbeuter`, then in `~/.newsbeuter` (the file should be named `urls`). If it doesn't find any, it will quit with an error message. I'm supposing that's what's happening in your case: since you're starting things from `/etc/rc.local`, your `$HOME` is not your user's, so Newsbeuter doesn't find the file and quits.

One way to correct this would be to `su` into your user before starting Newsbeuter.

Another would be to provide the path to `urls` explicitly with `--url-file=/home/username/.newsbeuter/urls` (and also `--cache-file`, probably `--config-file` as well).

Answer (score 0):

To see a possible error message, do `tmux set set-remain-on-exit` before the `tmux new-window`, and afterwards `attach` to the new window and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>Page Up</kbd>.